# Using Google Mock with pointer to interface

Tags: c++, c++17, googlemock

I have the following interface:

```
struct IBackgroundModel {
    virtual Image process(const Image& inputImage) = 0;
    virtual ~IBackgroundModel() = default;
};
```

and a test with a mock:

```
TEST_F(EnvFixture, INCOMPLETE) {
        struct BackgroundModelMock : IBackgroundModel {
            MOCK_METHOD1(process, Image(const Image& override));
        };
        std::unique_ptr<IBackgroundModel> model = std::make_unique<BackgroundModelMock>();
        Image input;
        Image output;
        EXPECT_CALL(model, process(input)).Will(Return(output));


        BackgroundModelFactory factory;
        factory.set(model.get());
        const auto result = factory.process(input);
    }
```

But I can't compile nor figure out what the error means:

```
error C2039: 'gmock_process': is not a member of 'std::unique_ptr<P,std::default_delete<P>>'
        with
        [
            P=kv::backgroundmodel::IBackgroundModel
        ]
C:\Source\Kiwi\Kiwi.CoreBasedAnalysis\Libraries\Core\Kiwi.Vision.Core.Native\include\Ptr.hpp(17): message : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<P,std::default_delete<P>>'
        with
        [
            P=kv::backgroundmodel::IBackgroundModel
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `EXPECT_CALL` takes reference, not a (smart) pointer. Secondly, it has to be reference to the concrete mock, not to the mocked class/interface. And thirdly, in latest gtest there is no `Will` funciton. There is `WillOnce` and `WillRepeadately`. So the fix is like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<BackgroundModelMock> model = std::make_unique<BackgroundModelMock>();
Image input;
Image output;
EXPECT_CALL(*model, process(input)).WillOnce(testing::Return(output));
```